# Can a Red Black Tree have a black node with a black descendant? Is this image wrong?

Tags: binary-search-trees, red-black-trees

How the story begins? I was learning about Red Black Trees on my own. When one opens the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), it can be read:

> (Conclusion) If a node N has exactly one child, it **must be a red child**, because if it were black, its NIL descendants would sit at a different black depth than N's NIL child, violating requirement 4.

I can understand this, but then when I looked the insertion algorithm, in the Insertion case I6 (outer grandchild), this illustration is shown (N is the new node inserted):

[image]

And I don't know if this does graphically represent the code that it is executed in that case (rotation + switching colors). Isn't it wrong? If a node that has only one child (G) should be red, shouldn't the nodes be painted in the opposite colors, i. e, U and P red, while G and N black?

**EDIT**

I think now I realize that the little black dots are other nodes in the tree, in this case seems the tree satisfies the required properties. But this still makes me think, **what would happen if N, P, G  and U were just all the nodes in the tree**? Would that arrangement of N,P,G and U be wrong? Suppose N<P<G<U, which of the following trees is the correct one?

tree 1 (what I thought initially, same as the Wikipedia image but without other nodes)
[image]

tree 2 (switched colors to avoid repetition of color in two consecutive levels)
[image]

tree 3
[image]

I think 3 is the correct since as I understand, the root and the implicit leaves must be always black. But I just want to be sure if It is ok that a black node has a black descendant too.